# Springboot version upgrade - my sql error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, gradle, jdbc, h2

We are trying to upgrade our project through `build.gradle`  dependencies :

- spring-boot from version `1.5.7` to `2.3.3`
- Gradle from version `Gradle-4.8-all` to `Gradle-6.4.1-all`

**We are getting the following error:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
    Migration V3__Sequence_Table.sql failed
    ---------------------------------------
    SQL State  : 42001
    Error Code : 42001
    Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "DELIMITER[*]
```

The `JDBC` connection `URL` was mentioned as below earlier.

```
o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:mysql://xxxxx:3306/mydb (MySQL 5.7)
```

This has been changed as below now,

```
o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory  : Database: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (H2 1.4)
```

Is this the cause of the above flyway migration error?

Comment: Is the SQL Flyway is trying to execute specific to MySQL? The H2 database might not be compatible with all SQL features MySQL has. Looks at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53047481/mysql-delimiter-in-h2?noredirect=1&lq=1 and the linked issue. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastian. Tried specifying MYSQL with `spring.datasource.platform=mysql` as mentioned in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247283/spring-boot-mysql-settings-are-not-working]. But it didn't workout.

Comment: Which database is correct in your project? Are you using MySQL or H2? I cannot reallly follow which one is the correct one.

Comment: yes, It is MySQL. @Sebastian

Comment: Ok, and you changed the JDBC URL to `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`?

Comment: NO, we are trying to upgrade the spring boot version. while we run the application in locally it has been taken JDBC: MySQL, when we have deployed into AWS, JDBC URL automatically changed form JDBC: MySQL to JDBC:h2:mem:  we need only JDBC: Mysql @Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem:**

`Run` command for `jar` file is a problem for this project `

`Dspring.config.location=run.properties`
this commad execute only run.properties

**solution:**

Instead of the above `run` command, you should try this run command for the `jar` file

```
  Dspring.config.additional-location=run.properties
```

I was try for my project and this was working well